# Shared web application for mysite

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016

Can I use one web application for the main portal and mysite

Or one application for each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the preferred way going ahead.

I would recommend having seperate web application for Intranet and mysites.

For **mysites** you are going to need "**User Profile service application**" . These services are  **web application scoped**.

**Keeping optimal performance and security in mind** Microsoft recommends it as a best practise to have **mysite on a seperate web application**.

Comment: Welcome @Chicago

Answer (score 0):

You can create both main portal and mysite under one web application but it is **recommended by Microsoft** to create **separate web application** for Mysite for better performance and manageability.

You can read [**this**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/my-sites-planning) post if you need help in setting Mysite.